# Owl carousel rails working in development mode but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

I have installed owl carousel rails gem, using spree 3.0.4,  followed the instructions.
but my code is working on localhost but not on heroku. I tried using js file instead of gem but that did not help as well.

here is the code its a template *_artist_show.html.erb*

```
<div class="carousel-container">
                            <h2 class="carousel-title">Our Skilled Artists</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="artists-brief" class="owl-carousel from-theblog-carousel from-theblog-wide" style="display:inline;">

                                    <%ArtistProfile.take(6).each do |artist|%>
                                        <article class="article">
                                            <div class="article-media-container">
                                                <a ><img src="<%=artist.a_img(:thumb)%>" class="img-responsive" alt="<%=artist.a_name%>"></a>
                                            </div><!-- End .article-media-container -->

                                            <div class="article-meta-box" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;">
                                                <span class="article-icon article-date-icon"></span>
                                                <span class="meta-box-text"><%=artist.a_dob%></span>
                                            </div><!-- End .article-meta-box -->

                                            <h3><a ><%=artist.a_name%></a></h3>
                                            <span class="meta-box-text"><%=truncate(artist.a_skills,length: 60)%></span>
                                            <hr/>
                                            <p><%=truncate(artist.a_brief,length: 100)%></p>
                                            <a href="/artist_profiles/<%=artist.id%>" class="readmore" role="button">Read More</a>
                                        </article><!-- End .article -->
                                    <%end%>    

                                </div><!-- End .container -->
                            </div><!-- End .container -->
                        </div><!-- End .carousel-container -->

<%=javascript_tag do%>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#artists-brief").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, 

      items : 2,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

    });
     $('.owl-pagination').css({"display":"none"});

    });
<%end%>
```

I also tried putting the js code in main js file but still it was working in dev but not on heroku. 
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enabled assests precompilation in production.

in the file **/config/environments/production.rb** make sure these are present.

> config.assets.compile = true
>
> config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']

if you havent automated assets precompilation in heroku then run the following to precompile assets

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

before you push.

Comment: thanks a lot for looking into it, but I already did it. However  I got the reason why it was not working, the data which was being pulled from db had chars like "(" ")" "\" '"'  there fore which were disrupting the code. once I cleaned it it started working. reason it was working on localhost was because I had only test data which was just simple string